# How to send DM to all server members (nextcord)

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

So, I'm planning to make my bot dm all members in the server to remind them to enter the giveaway

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    if args != None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            try:
                await member.send(args)
                print("'" + args + "' sent to: " + member.name)

            except:
                print("Couldn't send '" + args + "' to " + member.name)

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("You didn't provide a arguments.")
```

this code doesn't work

[image]

in terminal it appears like this. it's only try to dm the bot (Hu Tao) and no dm's coming from other members

Comment: Do you have member intents enabled?

Comment: ah yeah I didn't know about that before. now it fixed 
`intents = nextcord.Intents.default() 
intents.members = True 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-', intents=intents) 
`
Thank you @moinierer3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have intents enabled:

```
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
```

Now enable members for the intents:

```
intents.members = True
```

Update your client to use the intents:

```
client = commands.Bot(prefix, intents=intents)
```

Also, I'm not forcing you but DMing them all is a bad idea.